# How I can call dynamically an object over html in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, object

I have a dropdown menu in one html page and when I choose one option of this dropdown menu I link with `href` to another html page. In this html page I want to `console.log` some particular specifics of the option that I have chose(the specifics are javascript objects).

My question is how I can make this dynamically? To be more clear thing an analogy, I have a dropdown menu with fruits I choose orange, I href in orange.html and in this page I want to console the javascript object fruit.orange but I want this to be dynamically not static(just writing in orange.html fruit.orange because I know that I am in orange.html)

Is this feasible?
I hope my question is clear and not ambiguous

Comment: Some html+JS code (not necessarily the whole project but also a simplified example) would help people to provide an answer.

Comment: You can use `window.location.href` to determine on what page you are than just `console.log` object you want.

Answer (score 0):

By clicking on the option you need to store it so that on a new page you can find out which option was chosen. If you don't want to use a server that allows you to move the variable from one view to another, then you can use localStorage to save the variable.

> Adding some data to localStorage is as easy as using the setItem()
>   method. I'll use a generic key and value for the names, but they can
>   be any strings.

`localStorage.setItem('key', 'value')`

> If you want to get the value for a particular key, you'll use the
>   getItem() method.

`localStorage.getItem('key')`

Source: https://www.taniarascia.com/how-to-use-local-storage-with-javascript/

If you want the saved information to be automatically deleted once the browser is closed, you can use **sessionStorage** instead

> sessionStorage is similar to localStorage; the difference is that
>   while data in localStorage doesn't expire, data in sessionStorage is
>   cleared when the page session ends.

```
// Save data to sessionStorage
sessionStorage.setItem('key', 'value');

// Get saved data from sessionStorage
let data = sessionStorage.getItem('key');

// Remove saved data from sessionStorage
sessionStorage.removeItem('key');

// Remove all saved data from sessionStorage
sessionStorage.clear();
```

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how complex the object is, it's unwieldy to pass it through the form, which would leave you with the option of storing it via local storage, or grabbing it via AJAX. I would go with the latter, however this would essentially mean doing what you said you don't want to do, i.e. recognizing something about the `orange.html` page and making the call. To be clearer, this is something like what I would do:

On `orange.html` have an AJAX call:

```
  let xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest()

  xhttp.onreadystatechange = () => {
      if(this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
          let obj = this.responseText;
      }
  }

  xhttp.open("GET", "orange.js", true)
  xhttp.send()
```

Of course if you have a separate page for each dropdown (e.g. apple.html, orange.html, etc) you could just hardcode the correct object on each page, but with AJAX you can make your code dryer by having a single page the form submits to, and depending on the value of the dropdown, make a call to a separate AJAX file (e.g. orange.js, apple.js) OR a sinle js file and grab the correct object:

```
xhttp.open("GET", "fruit.js", true)
```

then:

```
let orange = obj.orange
```

I hope that makes sense.